# Optimizing error for PID based control of Line Following Robot

Tags: control-engineering, robotics, optimal-control

I am working to find the optimal PID gains of my line following robot. To do this, I need to optimize any performance index dependent on the error (a typical example is the integral absolute error). The problem is, I don't know how to setup IAE in terms of PID gains. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: (If I remember correctly. Take notes so you can easily go back to a previous point of stability if you depart from it.) Start with a straight line. P is the highest contributer. As P increases you begin to overshoot and the response rings. Then I helps damp out the overshoot and ringing. At this point you might add more P then I (if needed). D may not be required as (I believe) it helps control something that is fairly stable and not changing much (like a drawn line).

Comment: I should correct myself and say at the end of the above ...(unlike a drawn line).